# Что нужно для добавления информации о метке?

Tags: поддержка, метки, описание-метки

Есть метка [vk-streaming-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vk-streaming-api), она относительна новая и на данный момент всего 2 вопроса. Как добавить к ней описание?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. На странице метки под кратким описанием найти ссылку "подробнее...":

   [image]
2. Кнопка "Предложить описание метки" в самом низу:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Заполнить описание.
4. Ждать одобрения [от 5000+](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). Или отклонения.

---

Альтернативный план, повышенной сложности:

1. Набрать [20000+ репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).
2. Внести правку напрямую, без проверок другими участниками. Процедура аналогична вышеописанной, отличие будет только на странице метки.